# WebApplication crashes on some clients after update

Tags: vue.js, npm, tomcat9

I amb developing a web application with the frontent using typescript and vue, and the backend using spring. All deployed into a machine with tomcat9.

For some reason, everytime I update the application my boss calls me days later stating that the application stoped working. I then go check, but works fine for me, ask me boss to clear cache site and then it works for him to.

I dunno why, but this always happends to my boss and not me.

At first I thought this was happening cause I wasn't updating the version on the `package.json` file. But this doesn't solved the problem.

Any hint on what I can do to avoid this behaviour? Any workarounds would also be appreciated. As a developer I don't mind clearing the cache but our clients....

Comment: Did you check the logs to see if your boss's session is timing out?

Comment: I didn't but don't need to. His session is for sure timing out. But normally this just redirects the user to the login pages. Are you sugesting I can reproduce this behaviour by lating my session time out and then updating the app? This would make sense since I always updated the app without a session expired. If this is the case how I could fix it?